# Inulin reduction in Jerusalem Artichokes

Tags: storage-method, vegetables, food-preservation, chemistry

Last year we first planted Jerusalem Artichokes (Topinambour) in our vegetable garden. The plants did very well and we had quite a huge harvest. We found however that eating the tubers causes digestive problems.

I looked into why this is and found that the effect is caused by the presence of a carbohydrate called Inulin, which our digestive system can not process, but sadly the bacteria in our colons CAN (hence the nickname Fartichoke for this otherwise quite delicious produce).

I have found literature references saying that storing the tubers cold and dark for 6+ weeks will transform the Inulin into other forms of carb that can be digested. Since the harvests are quite huge and our cold storage room is limited, I was wondering if anyone here knows of a different method of Inulin reduction.

Any tips welcome, be they of a storage, preparation or preservation nature.

Comment: It turns out that this was a duplicate, and since the answers you'd already gotten were useful, I merged them into the old question. But your question itself actually provides some useful information (the problematic component is inulin, and cold storage helps), so if you'd like to post that as an answer to the other question, it'd be a valuable contribution!